# scale image when scroll ( Keeping good proportion)

Tags: jquery, scroll, scale

I'm trying to scale an image when the user scroll down.

It works fine, but the problem I'm having is that it doesn't keep the good proportion. What i mean is my image is 212 px width by 800px height. In scale is on scroll like it was a square image .. .

Here is my Jsfiddle which will make more sens i suppose . ..

Any help would be really amazing  :)

http://jsfiddle.net/mw73enz8/6/

```
<img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/2d9v77d.png"">
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

css:

```
img {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
}

$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var s = Math.min(400, $(document).scrollTop()) + 100;
    $("img").width(s).height(s);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    var width = $('img').width();
    var height = $('img').height();

    //set width,height to 0 now in order to get real width and height
    $('img').width(0).height(0);

    var ratio = width/height;


$(window).on("scroll", function() {

    console.log(ratio);
    var w = $(document).scrollTop();    
        $("img").width(w*ratio).height(w)
});

});
```

Comment: Hi Marius, Thank you :)

The thing is i want it to be invisible at the beginning - to make like a zoom in effect when the user scroll ...  with height in auto, the image appear at the beginning unfortunately :( DO you have any solution in mind ? Thank you for your time

Comment: Updated, this should work http://jsfiddle.net/mw73enz8/10/, if you want to display it bigger you can multiply the w with something

Comment: do you have any idea how to make this function to start after X pixels scrolldown ? (by any chance :) )